# C# Amcharts javascript

Tags: c#, amcharts

I input data `FinalResult`  of type `List<SummaryUptoToday>` from `C#` into `Amcharts` and Here is the definition of `SummaryUptoToday`

```
public class SummaryUptoToday : ICloneable
{
    public List<TradePositionSingle> StockList { get; set; }
    public List<PerformanceSingle> Performance { get; set; }
    public double Commission { get; set; }
    public double PNL { get; set; }
    public double NAV { get; set; }
    public double CashLeft { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public SummaryUptoToday() { }

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return ObjectCopier.Clone(this);
    }
}
```

and the definition of `PerformanceSingle` is

```
public class PerformanceSingle : ICloneable
{
    public MyData Stock { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int TradePositionToday { get; set; }
    public double Commission { get; set; }
    public double PNL { get; set; }
    public double NAV { get; set; }
    public double PNL2 { get; set; }

    public PerformanceSingle() { }

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return ObjectCopier.Clone(this);
    }
}
```

Now I want to add a series of graphs of each term in `List<PerformanceSingle> Performance` in the `FinalResult`(Maybe need `for loop`) with

```
Title:  Stock.Name
x-axis: Date
y-axis: PNL2
```

Then how could I do this in javascript languige as following(Here `data` is the imputed `FinalResult`)

```
    function createStockChart(data) {
        var chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();

        // DATASETS
        var dataSet1 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
        dataSet1.color = "#b0de09";
        dataSet1.fieldMappings = [{
            fromField: "NAV",
            toField: "NAV"
        }];
        dataSet1.dataProvider = data;
        dataSet1.categoryField = "Date";

        chart.dataSets = [dataSet1];

        // PANELS
        var stockPanel = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
        stockPanel.showCategoryAxis = true;
        stockPanel.title = "NAV";
        stockPanel.eraseAll = false;
        //stockPanel.addLabel(0, 100, "Click on the pencil icon on top-right to start drawing", "center", 16);

        var graph = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
        graph.title = "NAV";
        graph.valueField = "NAV";
        graph.bullet = "round";
        graph.bulletColor = "#FFFFFF";
        graph.bulletBorderColor = "#00BBCC";
        graph.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
        graph.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
        graph.bulletSize = 7;
        graph.lineThickness = 2;
        graph.lineColor = "#00BBCC";
        graph.useDataSetColors = false;
        graph.comparable = true;
        graph.compareField = "HSI";
        stockPanel.addStockGraph(graph);
```

Actually, the structure of my inputed data is following:

```
var data1 = [{
"Date": "2016-07-09",
"StockList": [{"Name": "H1", "PNL2": 20, "NAV2" : 20}, {"Name": "H2", "PNL2": 20, "NAV2" : 20}]
"NAV": 26.28,
"PNL": 7.61
}, {
"Date": "2016-07-10",
"StockList": [{"Name": "H1", "PNL2": 20, "NAV2" : 20}, {"Name": "H2", "PNL2": 20, "NAV2" : 20}]
"NAV": 27.55,
"PNL": 12.89
}];
```

What I want to do is first plot the main graph `NAV` and dynamically two graphs of `H1` and  `H2` with their `PNL2` against the `Date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert with C# but the dataProvider needs to be a JSON array of objects. Given you want to serialize this:

```
x-axis: Date
y-axis: PNL2
```

Your dataProvider array should be:

```
[{
  "Date": "...", //string representation of your date, such as "YYYY-MM-DD"
  "PNL2": 10.5,
},
//other array elements omitted
]
```

There are plenty of resources out there on serializing .NET objects to JSON. A brief search suggests that [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is the recommended framework for this.

Your graph's `valueField` needs to correspond to the `toField` in your `fieldMappings`. You can map the fields to the same name or from a different name to a new name. If you want to map `PNL2` to `NAV`, for example:

```
dataSet1.fieldMappings = [{
  fromField: "PNL2",
  toField: "NAV"
}]
// ...
graph.valueField = "NAV"; //maps to the toField
```

For simplicity's sake of the demo, I kept the PNL2 name the same and adjusted accordingly. `compareField` was removed since you only have one dataSet. If you're comparing multiple dataSets, then it can be placed back in. I also set the `dataDateFormat` to match my string YYYY-MM-DD dates in the Date `categoryField`.

```js
var data = [{
  "Date": "2016-07-09",
  "PNL2": 28.05
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-10",
  "PNL2": 30.84
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-11",
  "PNL2": 22.89
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-12",
  "PNL2": 26.67
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-13",
  "PNL2": 21.7
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-14",
  "PNL2": 24.54
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-15",
  "PNL2": 24.32
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-16",
  "PNL2": 31.48
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-17",
  "PNL2": 29.99
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-18",
  "PNL2": 33.67
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-19",
  "PNL2": 24.08
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-20",
  "PNL2": 34.17
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-21",
  "PNL2": 32.76
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-22",
  "PNL2": 28.59
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-23",
  "PNL2": 21.49
}];




function createStockChart(data) {
  var chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();
  chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";

  // DATASETS
  var dataSet1 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
  dataSet1.color = "#b0de09";
  dataSet1.fieldMappings = [{
    fromField: "PNL2",
    toField: "PNL2"
  }];
  dataSet1.dataProvider = data;
  dataSet1.categoryField = "Date";

  chart.dataSets = [dataSet1];

  // PANELS
  var stockPanel = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
  stockPanel.showCategoryAxis = true;
  stockPanel.title = "PNL2";
  stockPanel.eraseAll = false;
  //stockPanel.addLabel(0, 100, "Click on the pencil icon on top-right to start drawing", "center", 16);

  var graph = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
  graph.title = "PNL2";
  graph.valueField = "PNL2";
  graph.bullet = "round";
  graph.bulletColor = "#FFFFFF";
  graph.bulletBorderColor = "#00BBCC";
  graph.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
  graph.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
  graph.bulletSize = 7;
  graph.lineThickness = 2;
  graph.lineColor = "#00BBCC";
  graph.useDataSetColors = false;
  stockPanel.addStockGraph(graph);

  chart.addPanel(stockPanel);
  chart.write("chartdiv");
}

createStockChart(data);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Edit: To create these dynamically, you just need to make sure your graphs and dataSets/dataProviders point to the proper fields. For example, to combine everything into a single dataSet:

```
  //get the valueFields from the first element in the dataProvider array
  var valueFields = [];

  Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(function(field) {
    if (field !== "Date") {
      valueFields.push(field);
    }
  });

  //create your fieldMappings in your dataSet:
  // DATASETS
  var dataSet1 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
  dataSet1.color = "#b0de09";
  //create the mappings for each valueField
  dataSet1.fieldMappings = valueFields.map(function(valueField) {
    return {
      fromField: valueField,
      toField: valueField
    };
  });
  dataSet1.dataProvider = data;
  dataSet1.categoryField = "Date";

  //create your graphs based on the valueFields:
  valueFields.forEach(function(valueField) {

    var graph = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
    graph.title = valueField;
    graph.valueField = valueField;
    // other settings omitted
    stockPanel.addStockGraph(graph);
  });
```

And here's a demo for that:

```js
var data1 = [{
  "Date": "2016-07-09",
  "PNL2": 12.84,
  "NAV": 26.28,
  "PNL": 7.61
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-10",
  "PNL2": 11.62,
  "NAV": 27.55,
  "PNL": 12.89
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-11",
  "PNL2": 16.95,
  "NAV": 30.66,
  "PNL": 7.91
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-12",
  "PNL2": 13.5,
  "NAV": 28.9,
  "PNL": 14.58
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-13",
  "PNL2": 13.26,
  "NAV": 25.72,
  "PNL": 12.47
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-14",
  "PNL2": 12.29,
  "NAV": 20.53,
  "PNL": 6.27
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-15",
  "PNL2": 12.86,
  "NAV": 34.96,
  "PNL": 14.28
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-16",
  "PNL2": 16.34,
  "NAV": 32.99,
  "PNL": 15.31
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-17",
  "PNL2": 15.85,
  "NAV": 24.26,
  "PNL": 9.79
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-18",
  "PNL2": 15.09,
  "NAV": 35.05,
  "PNL": 7.54
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-19",
  "PNL2": 10.52,
  "NAV": 24.09,
  "PNL": 6.72
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-20",
  "PNL2": 15.99,
  "NAV": 29.35,
  "PNL": 11.47
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-21",
  "PNL2": 12.31,
  "NAV": 32.26,
  "PNL": 7.16
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-22",
  "PNL2": 13.77,
  "NAV": 26.18,
  "PNL": 6.46
}, {
  "Date": "2016-07-23",
  "PNL2": 12.13,
  "NAV": 30.22,
  "PNL": 10.94
}];


function createStockChart(data) {
  var chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();
  chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";
  var valueFields = [];

  //get the valueFields from the first element in the dataProvider array
  Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(function(field) {
    if (field !== "Date") {
      valueFields.push(field);
    }
  });

  
  var dataSet1 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
  dataSet1.color = "#b0de09";
  //create your field mappings for each valueField
  dataSet1.fieldMappings = valueFields.map(function(valueField) {
    return {
      fromField: valueField,
      toField: valueField
    };
  });
  dataSet1.dataProvider = data;
  dataSet1.categoryField = "Date";

  chart.dataSets = [dataSet1];

  // PANELS
  var stockPanel = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
  stockPanel.showCategoryAxis = true;
  stockPanel.title = "PNL2";
  stockPanel.eraseAll = false;
  //stockPanel.addLabel(0, 100, "Click on the pencil icon on top-right to start drawing", "center", 16);

  //create a graph for each valueField
  valueFields.forEach(function(valueField) {
    var graph = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
    graph.title = valueField;
    graph.valueField = valueField;
    graph.bullet = "round";
    graph.bulletColor = "#FFFFFF";
    graph.bulletBorderColor = "#00BBCC";
    graph.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
    graph.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
    graph.bulletSize = 7;
    graph.lineThickness = 2;
    graph.lineColor = "#00BBCC";
    graph.useDataSetColors = false;
    stockPanel.addStockGraph(graph);
  });

  chart.addPanel(stockPanel);
  chart.write("chartdiv");
}

createStockChart(data1);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
```

Edit 2: The chart doesn't support nested arrays. Your `StockList` array needs to be flattened into the top level object. For example:

```
var data1 = [{
"Date": "2016-07-09",
"H1_PNL2": 20, 
"H1_NAV2" : 20
"H2_PNL2": 20, 
"H2_NAV2" : 20,
"NAV": 26.28,
"PNL": 7.61
}, {
"Date": "2016-07-10",
"H1_PNL2": 20, 
"H1_NAV2" : 20
"H2_PNL2": 20, 
"H2_NAV2" : 20,
"NAV": 27.55,
"PNL": 12.89
}];
```

From there you can create your graphs and dataSets accordingly using H1_PNL2 and H2_PNL2 as valueFields for your H1/H2 graphs.

Comment: sorry the essenstial thing is that how to plot the graphs dynamically, for example, The data List includes three components `H1`,`H2`,` H3`, then we should plot three graphs respectively, but the number and content of graph can not be ploted manually, we need some thing like `for loop`?

Comment: Sure, you can use a for loop to create your graphs and dataSets. You just need to create the dataProviders for each dataSet (or combine it into one) into an array of objects like I described.

Comment: @ xorspark yeah, could you show some example of `for loop` of `dataSet` or `graph`, I don't know the type of such languageto to use `for loop`,  maybe a simple sample can help me easily solve this problem?

Comment: I added an example of creating fieldMappings and graphs based on the valueFields in your data. You can use it as a starting point.

Comment: @ xorspark here `data[0]` means the array of `Date`, then `Date[1]` is the array of `PNL2`?

Comment: If one of component again is a list eg   "Date": "2016-07-23",
  "PNL2": 12.13,
  "NAV": 30.22,
  "PNL": 10.94

Comment: data is an array of objects. data[0] corresponds to the first object in the array containing `Date`, `PNL2`, `NAV` and `PNL`. Like I said, the dataProvider must be an array of JavaScript objects (see the code).

Comment: I have made my question more clear, please see the updated question, thx

Comment: I updated my answer. The chart doesn't support nested arrays. You'll need to augment your array accordingly. See my example.

Comment: @ xorspark is it possible to change into such flaten array here, since the inputed data  is not allowed to be changed?